# Custom error handlers in Slim 3 not working

Tags: php, slim, slim-3

I want to override the default error handlers in Slim 3 and respond with JSON instead of the default HTML page. But I can't get it to work, my custom handlers are ignored completely and I can't figure out why.

My project structure looks like this:

```
api/
  public/
    index.php
  src/
    config/
      database.php
      handlers.php
      settings.php
    models/
      product.php
    routes/
      products.php
```

My `index.php` looks like this:

```php
<?php

use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
require __DIR__ . '/../src/config/database.php';

// Instantiate the app
$settings = require __DIR__ . '/../src/config/settings.php';
$app = new \Slim\App(['settings' => $settings]);

// Set up handlers
$container = $app->getContainer();
require __DIR__ . "/../src/config/handlers.php";

// Register routes
require __DIR__ . '/../src/routes/products.php';

// Run app
$app->run();
```

And my `handlers.php` file with all the custom error handlers looks like this:

```php
<?php 

/**
 * Custom global error handler.
 */
$container['errorHandler'] = function($container) {
  return function ($request, $response, $exception) use ($container) {
      return $response->withStatus(500)
          ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
          ->write(json_encode(array(
              'error' => 'INTERNAL_ERROR',
              'error_message' => 'Something went wrong internally.',
              'status_code' => '500',
              'trace' => $exception.getTraceAsString()
            ), JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));    
  };
};

/**
* Custom global PHP error handler.
*/
$container['phpErrorHandler'] = function($container) {
  return $container['errorHandler'];
};

/**
* Custom 404 Not Found error handler.
*/
$container['notFoundHandler'] = function($container) {
  return function ($request, $response) use ($container) {
      return $response->withStatus(404)
          ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
          ->write(json_encode(array(
              'error' => 'NOT_FOUND',
              'error_message' => 'Endpoint was not found. Check API documentation for valid endpoints.',
              'status_code' => '404',
            ), JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));    
  };
};

/**
* Custom 405 Not Allowed error handler.
*/
$container['notAllowedHandler'] = function($container) {
  return function ($request, $response, $methods) use ($container) {
      return $response->withStatus(405)
          ->withHeader('Allow', implode(', ', $methods))
          ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
          ->write(json_encode(array(
              'error' => 'NOT_ALLOWED',
              'error_message' => 'HTTP request method is not allowed. Method must be of: ' . implode(', ', $methods),
              'status_code' => '405',
            ), JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));    
  };
};
```

What I have tried so far:

- Adding all handlers before creating `$app` and loading the `$container` into it.
- Unset the existing handler before creating a custom one, like so:
  `unset($app->getContainer()['notFoundHandler']);`

I just can't wrap my head around what goes wrong and why I am still getting the default HTML views when an error is thrown.

Comment: You'r code (the relevant part, without db config, routes, etc...) works for me. I'm suspicious you might have done something wrong in products.php. Try running your code without including products.php and see what happens.

Comment: @Nima, I went through the code in products.php and notices what was wrong. I was instantiating a new ```$app = new \Slim\App;```. Since all the routes inside this file worked I thought it had something to do with my handler file. Cheers for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Nima I figured out that I had accidentally created a new instance of the `$app = new \Slim\App;` inside my `products.php` file. Removing that got it to work.